# problem with making a game timer in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I made a small game with Python that randomly have an image change the location and the player should click on the images to earn points. However, I wanted to make a timer in the game so the user will have only For example 10 seconds of time.

I really couldn't make it work with mainloop.

In this code, the `checker`  method is running only once and the `rpl` method is the game method.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
import time



st=0
en=0
point=0

root=tk.Tk()
root.title("Game 2")
root.geometry("450x400")
root.resizable(0,0)
img = tk.PhotoImage(file="dice\\1.png")
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=100, height=100)

# canvas.place(x=400,y=100,anchor='center')
canvas.create_image(50,50,image=img,anchor='center')
bt1=tk.Button(text="Start",width=10)
bt1.place(x=0,y=0,anchor=tk.NW)
lbl1=tk.Label(root,text="Score: "+str( point),font=('robot',20))
lbl1.place(x=10,y=370,anchor=tk.W)
lbl2=tk.Label(root,text="Time: "+str(st-en),font=('robot',20))
lbl2.place(x=150,y=370,anchor=tk.W)


def rpl(event):
    global st
    global point
   
    point+=1
    lbl1.configure(text="Score: "+str( point))
    canvas.place(x=random.randint(75,350),y=random.randint(75,300),anchor='center')

def start():
    global st
    st=time.perf_counter()
    print("START !")
    canvas.place(x=random.randint(75, 350), y=random.randint(75, 300), anchor='center')

def checker():
    total=time.perf_counter()-st
    lbl2.configure(text="Time: " +str(int(total)))
    if(total>=10):
        print ("Game over")
        canvas.configure(width=0,height=0)
        lblend=tk.Label(root,text="Game over\nYou got "+str(point)+" Points")
        lblend.configure(font=('robot',20),fg='Red')
        lblend.place(x=225,y=200,anchor='center')

checker()
canvas.bind('<Button-1>',rpl)
bt1.configure(command=start)
tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the after method to call a function after a specified number of milliseconds.

To use it as a timer call it again from the function it calls, until the timer is 0 when you can call the 'game over' part of the code.

You'll need to cancel the timer and restart it when the user clicks the dice.

The following code should work but might have a minor bug regarding cancelling the timer.

Fixed bug with timer speeding up.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
import time

countdown = None
en = 0
time = 10
point = 0

root=tk.Tk()
root.title("Game 2")
root.geometry("450x400")
root.resizable(0,0)
img = tk.PhotoImage(file="dice1.png")
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=100, height=100)

# canvas.place(x=400,y=100,anchor='center')
canvas.create_image(50,50,image=img,anchor='center')
bt1=tk.Button(text="Start",width=10)
bt1.place(x=0,y=0,anchor=tk.NW)
lbl1=tk.Label(root,text="Score: "+str( point),font=('robot',20))
lbl1.place(x=10,y=370,anchor=tk.W)
lbl2=tk.Label(root,text=f"Time: {time}",font=('robot',20))
lbl2.place(x=150,y=370,anchor=tk.W)


def rpl(event):
    global point, countdown, time
    root.after_cancel(countdown)
    root.after(1000, timer)
    time = 10
    lbl2.configure(text=f'Time: {time}')
    point+=1
    lbl1.configure(text="Score: "+str( point))
    canvas.place(x=random.randint(75,350),y=random.randint(75,300),anchor='center')

def start():
    global countdown
    countdown = root.after(1000, timer)
    print("START !")
    canvas.place(x=random.randint(75, 350), y=random.randint(75, 300), anchor='center')

def timer():
  global time
  if time >0:
    time -= 1
    lbl2.configure(text=f'Time: {time}')
    countdown = root.after(1000, timer)
  else:
    checker()
    
def checker():   
    canvas.configure(width=0,height=0)
    lblend=tk.Label(root,text="Game over\nYou got "+str(point)+" Points")
    lblend.configure(font=('robot',20),fg='Red')
    lblend.place(x=225,y=200,anchor='center')

canvas.bind('<Button-1>',rpl)
bt1.configure(command=start)
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you very much. by changing a bit in your code my problem solved.
i just deleted these in  `rpl` :

`root.after(1000, timer)
    `time = 10`
    `lbl2.configure(text=f'Time: {time}')`

I Workes now ! thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @norie the problem solved. i just deleted 3 line in `rpl` from his code.

```
def rpl(event):
    global point, countdown, time
    root.after_cancel(countdown)
    root.after(1000, timer)
    time = 10
    lbl2.configure(text=f'Time: {time}')
    point+=1
    lbl1.configure(text="Score: "+str( point))
    canvas.place(x=random.randint(75,350),y=random.randint(75,300),anchor='center')
```